# Rolling 12 month data - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

First post so please be patient :)
I want to count the number of customers that have placed an order in a specific month and find the number of orders they have placed in that month and the 11 months prior to that month. I'm really not sure where to start so any help would be greatly appreciate, I also realise this is pretty vague so there may be a few follow up questions

I currently have a table of customerIDs, orderIDs and the date of their order like the below:

```html
CustomerID OrderID   OrderDate
1234       5678     Dec-16
1234       5679     Jan-17
1235       5680     Jan-17
```

This data would return the results:

```html
Date      CustomerCount   12MonthOrderCount
Jan 2017  2               3
Dec 2016  1               1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample data for your tables, explain how the tables join (if it's not obvious) and also your desired results from that sample data. You can check out a site [like this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for help in formatting data in a way that works nicely here on SO.

Comment: You also need to decide which DBMS you are actually using. mysql <> sql server and the answer will be pretty different for each of them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have added sample data and the desired result from the table data, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using T-SQL you can use below query

```
select t1.CusttomerIdfrom table1 t1
outer apply
(
    select top 1 t2.CId, t2.OrderId from table2 t2 
    where t2.CID = t1.CustomerId and [Date] = specificDate 
)q
```

and you have to select count of needded fields.

also you can use some nested selection query.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many unknowns in your question, I took the liberty of making many, many assumptions. One of them is that you use MSSQL. This code might point you ine one possible direction.

```
USE TEMPDB

DECLARE @Period INT
SET @Period = YEAR ( '20190101') * 100 + MONTH ('20190101') 

CREATE TABLE #T (CustID INT, OrderInPeriod INT, NumberOfOrders INT)

INSERT INTO #T 
SELECT CustID, 0, 0
FROM Customers

UPDATE #T
SET OrderInPeriod = 1 
FROM Orders AS O
WHERE #T.CustID = O.CustID
  AND YEAR (OrderDate) * 100 + MONTH (OrderDate) = @Period


UPDATE #T
SET NumberOfOrders = ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Orders AS O
                       WHERE #T.CustID = O.CustID
                         AND OrderDate > DATEADD (YEAR, -1, '20190101')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a window function for this [see here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/)

If you haven't checked them out already, I would do so.

Answer (score 0):

To get the base table, use aggregation:

```
select year(orderdate), month(orderdate), count(*) as num_orders
from orders o
group by year(orderdate), month(orderdate);
```

Then for the 12-month, you can do:

```
select year(orderdate), month(orderdate), count(*) as num_orders,
       (select count(*)
        from orders o2
        where year(o2.orderdate) * 100 + month(o2.orderdate) > year(o.orderdate) * 100 + month(o.orderdate) - 12 and
              year(o2.orderdate) * 100 + month(o2.orderdate) <= year(o.orderdate) * 100 + month(o.orderdate)
       ) as num_12month_orders
from orders o
group by year(orderdate), month(orderdate);
```

You can also do this with variables, but that gets a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to find out how many orders in the present month.

1. figure out how to turn the text in your OrderDate columns to a `DATE` datatype.
2. use the appropriate date arithmetic in WHERE statements.

1:  This kind of expression gets you a `DATE` showing the first day of the month from `Mon yy`   This example returns `2018-02-01`.

```
     SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-','Feb-18'), '%e-%b-%y')
```

So, you can use this sort of query to get your table with `DATE` values

```
 SELECT CustomerID, OrderID,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-',OrderDate), '%e-%b-%y') OrderDate
   FROM table
```

Try it. Convince yourself it works correctly on your data.

2: Use those `DATE` values in your WHERE clause. To do this, you need to know that [the `LAST_DAY(CURDATE())` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) gives the last day of this month.  And you need to know that `LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` gives the first day of this month.

So, to count all by customer id in the present month, do this

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) CustomerCount, CustomerId
   FROM orders
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-',OrderDate), '%e-%b-%y') >= 
                                      LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-',OrderDate), '%e-%b-%y') < 
                                      LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  GROUP BY CustomerId
```

Similarly this gets you the count for the year ending at the end of this month.

```
     SELECT COUNT(*) 12MonthOrderCount, CustomerId
   FROM orders
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-',OrderDate), '%e-%b-%y') >= 
                                      LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(' 1-',OrderDate), '%e-%b-%y') < 
                                      LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  GROUP BY CustomerId
```

Then you need to generate your overall result set, requiring you to JOIN those two subqueries

```
   SELECT CustomerId, CustomerCount, 12MonthOrderCount
     FROM ( /* the query showing the full year data */ ) yr
     FROM ( /* the query showing the month data */ ) mon ON yr.CustomerId=mo.CustomerId
```

You can try it all here.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/riyXu8MVjJKNWfWVQLmjUG/0

**Pro tip**: It should be obvious by now that storing dates in `DATE` columns makes life much easier when you're doing this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the results you want.

```
select count (distinct CustomerID) as 'CustomerCount', count (OrderID) as '12MonthOrderCount' 
from orders
where  (OrderDate <= '2017-01-01' AND OrderDate >= '2016-01-01')
```